# Two-column unordered list - keeping each li's content in one column

Tags: css

Best described by [example](https://jsfiddle.net/dkjLsnyz/).

I have two issues that I couldn't solve after hours of researching.

1) Stop HTML separating a single li content. For example, we can see that Group C heading in rendered in the first column, and the rest is rendered in the second.

2) Render the OK button so that it is out of the ul - in the left or right corner of the drop-down room.

```
<div>
  <span style='cursor:pointer; float:right'>
                                    <div class="btn-group pull-right">
                                        <button id = 'majic' type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>
  </button>

  <ul style='padding:10px; width:auto' class="dropdown-menu zeon-search-settings-dropdwown-menu zeon-two-columns-ul">
    <li class="dropdown-submenu zeon-dropdown-submenu">
      <div class='section-heading-3'>Group A</div>
      <div>
        <label class='zeon-input-label'>
          <input id="white_agreements_filter" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" checked class='zeon-checkbox' />Choice</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label class='zeon-input-label'>
          <input id="black_agreements_filter" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" checked class='zeon-checkbox' />Choice</label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown-submenu zeon-dropdown-submenu">
      <div class='section-heading-3'>Group B</div>
      <div>
        <label class='zeon-input-label'>
          <input id="cash_payment_filter" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" checked class='zeon-checkbox' />Choice</label>
      </div>
      <li class="dropdown-submenu zeon-dropdown-submenu">
        <div class='section-heading-3'>Group C</div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-1">

          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-7">
            <form>
              <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="optradio">
                < </label>
                  <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="optradio">=
                  </label>
                  <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="optradio">>
                  </label>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input class="form-control input-sm" id="inputsm" type="text" placeholder='количетсво дней'>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <div class='section-heading-3'>Group D</div>
        <div>
          <label class='zeon-input-label'>
            <input id="full_package_filter" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" checked class='zeon-checkbox' />Choice</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label class='zeon-input-label'>
            <input id="not_full_package_filter" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" checked class='zeon-checkbox' />Choice</label>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <button id='vendor_list_filter_ok_button' type="button" class="next btn btn-default btn-sm pull-left">ОК</button>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Your fiddle only shows a white background... no content.

Comment: Can you check it now ?

Comment: Click the icon in the right upper corner

Comment: @Scott, there is a "config" like icon on the right :)

Comment: Ha! okay.. doi! Yeah.. missed the icon, it's there. Sorry...

Comment: Are you using Chrome to display this HTML code?

Comment: No. IE renders incorrectly as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flexbox` for that (You can play with the height of the `ul.dropdown-menu`, if you add more height the group-c block will move to the left column)

This is the added css:

```
.open>ul.dropdown-menu {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px !important;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 250px;
}
ul.dropdown-menu li {
  width: 50%;
}
```

Here is the working jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/p6yf17du/

### Update

If you don't care (or if you can change the markup) about the order of the elements you can use:

```
.open>ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: flex;
    width: 400px !important;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

This will change the order of your elements from

```
A | C
B | D
```

to

```
A | B
C | D
```

However, this way you don't need to set the height of the menu (only the width, which makes sense to me).

You can check here:
https://jsfiddle.net/m0rg1uoe/

Comment: Well, if I don't get any better solution, I will accept tick your answer as solution. And yet, what I don't like in this approach is that I have to manually set the height and width of the element which makes the css class not portable and the code not re-usable

Comment: @EdgarNavasardyan, definitely agree with that, trying to come with a better solution. Thought I will just put it here until I find something better :)

Comment: @EdgarNavasardyan, check the update on my answer, might be the solution for you :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/a2n14bu7/    
There are some issues concerning the fixed width. If one of the lines are longer, than we get unpleasant results. Whereas if we omit the fixed width option, css automatically adjusts the width due to "white-space: nowrap;"

Comment: You can add `white-space: normal;` to the `label` element

Comment: Dekel, I've accepted your answer because you so much contributed to the quesiton. It's off-topic, and yet, white-space makes the line to be wrapped (as in Excel). Instead, is there any method to make the entire dropdown width become wider ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122781/discussion-between-dekel-and-edgar-navasardyan).

Answer (score 2):

You can try to solve this issue adding to last `<li>` element the `column-span` property. Applying this rule with value `all` it will force the last `<li>` element to cover all the columns.

For example see the following code:

*HTML:*

```
...
<li class="dropdown-submenu btn-confirm">
    <button id='vendor_list_filter_ok_button' type="button" class="next btn btn-default btn-sm pull-left">ОК</button>
</li>
...
```

*CSS*:

```
.btn-confirm {
  -webkit-column-span: all;
          column-span: all;
}
```

Once that last element cover both columns, also `Group C` heading will displayed correctly.

You can find a live demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dkjLsnyz/1/).

---

**Attention**: `column` and `column-span` properties have some issues in different browsers. See [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=column-span) website and check browsers support.

Comment: If the content of `group-b` will be 3 divs (and not 1) that group will break into the right column.

Comment: @Dekel I understand the issue. I'll look for some solution.

Comment: Anyway, I liked the `column-span: all;` thing, you got vote from me on that :)

Comment: @Dekel Unfortunately I didn't find any good way to solve the problem for whichever number of divs. For 3 divs is enough to add `margin-bottom: 10px;` to `zeon-dropdown-submenu` css class.

Comment: You can check my answer :) I will try also to see if I find a solution using your approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
.zeon-dropdown-submenu {
    margin-top: 10px;
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: The same comment as for the below-suggested solution - adjusting min-height for a fixed value is not reusable